# text box prevents use of keyboard

Tags: 12.04, text

Almost every time I try to play a game on my laptop, the textbox appears and I can't use my keyboard. My laptop runs on Ubuntu 12.04 and I can't figure out how to disable/delete the textbox. It always appears on the downleft corner. Is it at all deleteable and if so´, how to delete it.
!http://prntscr.com/6808o9

Comment: The title is there to summarize the problem with a few words. As some pages here only show the title of the question and no content preview, your post will get very few attention. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/588196/edit) your title to increase the chance of getting a good answer. Oh, and welcome to AskUbuntu.com by the way... :-)

Comment: Hey, thank you for help. still have a problem :D

Comment: You should edit your question to include the image as a image and not link to improve quality.